# how to add dynamic columns in fixed data table

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-columns, fixed-data-table

I am trying to acheive a dynamicallly populated columns with data, using facebooks's fixed data table. I receive data with columns ranging from 10 - 100. So my intent was to create columns dynamically. Below is what I have tried

```js
Class App extensd React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
            <Table
              rowHeight={50}
              headerHeight={30}
              groupHeaderHeight={30}
              rowsCount={10}
              width={tableWidth}
              height={500}
              {...this.props}>
              
            {["firstName","lastName","bs","email"].forEach(function(columnName){
            return <Column
                    columnKey={columnName}
                    header={ <Cell>Header</Cell>}
                    cell={<Cell>Cell Content</Cell>}
                    width={200}
  />
  )
    }
})}
```

It doesn't work. Has anyone tried anything like that before? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have misspelled **extends**. Also the tags you open needs to be closed with closing tags if there are child components inside

Comment: In addition to the misspellings, the `forEach` method does not return a new array; you need to use `map` instead.

Comment: Thanks @JeffWooden. That was really dumb me.

Answer (score 4):

What worked was, replacing forEach with map. Thanks @jeff-Wooden.

```js
Class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
            <Table
              rowHeight={50}
              headerHeight={30}
              groupHeaderHeight={30}
              rowsCount={10}
              width={tableWidth}
              height={500}
              {...this.props}>
              
            {["firstName","lastName","bs","email"].map(function(columnName){
            return <Column
                    columnKey={columnName}
                    header={ <Cell>Header</Cell>}
                    cell={<Cell>Cell Content</Cell>}
                    width={200}
  />
  )
    }
})}
```